# How can you determine if a proc call  is still free or bound?

Tags: ruby

I'd like to see if a proc call with the same arguments will give the same results every time. `pureproc` called with arguments is free, so every time  I call `pureproc(1,1)`, I'll get the same result. `dirtyproc` called with arguments is bound within its environment, and thus even though it has the same arity as `pureproc`, its output will depend on the environment.

```
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :001 > envx = 1
=> 1 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :003 > pureproc = Proc.new{ |a,b| a+b }
 => # 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :004 > dirtyproc = Proc.new{ |a,b| a+b+envx }
```

How can I programmatically determine whether a called proc or a method is free, as defined by only being bound over the variables that must be passed in? Any explanation of bindings, local variables, etc would be welcome as well.

Comment: I have a feeling that this is equivalent to solving the Halting Problem, but I cannot prove it.

Comment: LOL - I wasn't looking for a solution to the Halting Problem - just some info about what Ruby 'knows' about Procs in so far as the scope of variables they are referring to.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can parse the source using some gem like sourcify, take out all the tokens, and check if there is anything that is a variable. But note that this is a different concept from the value of the proc/method call being constant. For example, if you had things like `Time.now` or `Random.new` in your code, that does not require any variable to be defined, but will still vary every time you call. Also, what would you want to be the case when a proc has `envx - envx`? That will remain constant, but will still affect the code in the sense that it will return an error unless `envx` is defined.

Comment: This and other concerns convince me that it is pretty tricky if not impossible to 'know' idempotence of a function in Ruby. I'm still looking for an answer about whether it as closed over any variables that were not locally defined however

Answer (score 0):

Hm, tricky. There's the `parameters` method that tells you about expected arguments (note how they are optional cause you are using a procs, not lambdas).

```
pureproc.parameters
=> [[:opt, :a], [:opt, :b]] 
dirtyproc.parameters
=> [[:opt, :a], [:opt, :b]]
```

As for determining whether or not one of the closed over variables are actually used to compute the return value of the proc, walking the AST comes to mind (there are gems for that), but seems cumbersome. My first idea was something like `dirtyproc.instance_eval { local_variables }`, but since both closures close over the same environment, that obviously doesn't get you very far...

The overall question though is: if you want to make sure something is pure, why not make it a proper method where you don't close over the environment in the first place?

Comment: Thanks Michael, and the 'def' trick may be helpful if I were defining the function - but it's more in the case of library (or testing) code interrogating an existing Proc of potentially unknown origin. I suppose AST could be a method of last resort.